# Loop through variables to apply ordered mapping to variable

Tags: python, loops, mapping

my data set [Original Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFFDx.png) has a few quality variables in it that I am trying to convert into a numerical form, I have made a dictionary to save the mappings and added a variable to show all the variables that need to be converted.

```
qual_mappings = {'Po': 1, 'Fa': 2, 'TA': 3, 'Gd': 4, 'Ex': 5, 'Missing': 0, 'NA': 0}

qual_vars = ['ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond',
             'HeatingQC', 'KitchenQual', 'FireplaceQu',
             'GarageQual', 'GarageCond'
            ]
```

However, I am struggling to create the correct loop that can go through each of these variables as each of my attempts to far has failed, can someone please help me create a working loop model that can achieve this?

[Updated Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJLGl.png) This shows what I am trying to accomplish using Python, as you can see all the quality variables have been replaced by a corresponding number based around the mapping. (I don't have a working model I made a separate dataset using Excel just to show what I am looking to do).

Comment: Which dataset are you trying to convert? None of `qual_vars` can be converted to an `int` type. You should show your desired output and what you have tried so far by showing us your code.

Comment: Hi, sorry I have now added a table showing what the data looks like before as well as version for what I want it to look like. I haven't included any sample code though as honestly; I don't think my ideas were remotely close to what it should be.